# How to git-diff a file against "theirs" version after resolving conflicts

Tags: git, git-merge, githooks, git-diff, pre-commit-hook

In a pre-commit hook, I want to make sure that nobody (except 1 person) is able to change restricted_file.txt

The hook needs to handle the case when someone performs 'git pull' or 'git merge some_branch', obtains the latest restricted_file.txt but something_else.txt causes a conflict.

He resolves the conflict and keep "theirs" version of restricted_file.txt, perform 'git add' and 'git commit'.

At this point, pre-commit hook is executed and it identifies that restricted_file.txt will be committed.
We want to allow the commit only if the file is identical to what it came from 'git pull' or 'git merge' (in other words, if he kept "theirs" version).

Does anybody know if it is possible to determine if a file is identical to "theirs" during a conflict resolution?

**Something equivalent to the following non-existent command:**

```
git diff --cached --against_theirs -- restricted_file.txt
```

Comment: Why don't you compare the cached version of restricted file with that of the updated upstream. i.e diff the cached version with that on the incoming upstream branch.

Comment: This makes sense when you do everything manually because you know where are you merging from... but in a script we have to determine what is the incoming branch of the conflicting merge / pull.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`git diff --cached MERGE_HEAD -- restricted_file.txt` will do the job.  This works because (and hence, also, if and only if) `MERGE_HEAD` contains the SHA-1 ID of the commit being merged-in, i.e., the "theirs" version.

(Upon stopping for a conflicted or `--no-commit` merge, `git merge` writes that SHA-1 to the special `MERGE_HEAD` reference.)